# PHP Session_ Destroy or unset or Clear

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to clear a login session but whats the correct way to do this?

```
function logout(){

                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION = array();

                    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
                    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
                    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
                    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
                    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
                    }
                        session_destroy();
                        header ("Location: index.php");
    }
```

Comment: You have already pasted the example code [from PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#example-4036). What makes you believe it is not correct?

Comment: i was told by someone i should not destroy the session but want to know what the best way of doing this is?

Comment: Unless that someone offered specific arguments, or had knowledge of very specific and unique requirements your application has (quite unlikely), then their advice was generic. So it's generic advice from PHP.net versus generic advice from "someone".

Comment: ok so for the logout this is perfectly fine to destroy the session?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply open the [manual page for session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) and find all the necessary information, quote:

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie.
>
> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

Example 2209. Destroying a session with $_SESSION

```
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```